# gaps on left side of div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried margin and padding both at 0 and it still has a gap on the left side.

I have tried 0 on padding and that tends to make my bar too skinny for my taste and still doesn't fix the fact gap on the left. I can't seem to find a place that says to do anything other than padding 0; and margin 0; so I am kind of at a loss. and it's probably that I just completely overlooked.

The javascript to make my header move up and down with my page then lock to the top

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  getsticky()
};
var header = document.getElementById('myHeader');
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function getsticky() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #141414;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.Buttons {
  background-color: #141414;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 24px text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='header' id="myHeader">
  <H2><button class="Buttons"><a href = 'Pricing.html'>Pricing!</a></button>
    <button class="Buttons"><a href = 'About me.html'>About me</a></button>
    <button class="Buttons"><a href = 'placeholder.html'>Contact me!</a></button>
  </H2>
</div>

<div style="height:2000px">
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not position:fixed, then no need for javascript

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is this.

```
 body{
   margin:0!important
 }
```

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  getsticky()
};
var header = document.getElementById('myHeader');
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function getsticky() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0!important
}

.header {
  background-color: #141414;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.Buttons {
  background-color: #141414;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 24px text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='header' id="myHeader">
  <H2><button class="Buttons"><a href = 'Pricing.html'>Pricing!</a></button>
    <button class="Buttons"><a href = 'About me.html'>About me</a></button>
    <button class="Buttons"><a href = 'placeholder.html'>Contact me!</a></button>
  </H2>
</div>

<div style="height:2000px">
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
  <p>Scroll</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Always nicer to have the demo in the answer.

Comment: no problem :) @BlackestNight mark is at answer then :) glad I helped you.

Comment: @mplungjan what did I do to not have it be a demo?

Comment: @BlackestNight he replied to my answer not your question :) I did not input demo here but as URL

Comment: @BlackestNight but yes, I had to make a snippet out of your code too. Now you know

Comment: @BlackestNight you you please checkmark this answer so your question will be solved? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Lubo Masura explained, the reason of your issue is the margin automatically set on the body of an html element.

I made a demo you can find here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wilson-92657?file=/index.html

I changed the background of the links to blue just so you can see where the links are.

To notice I updated both your markup and styles to simplify it, as there were a couple of things which could have been improved:

- Best practice to always name your classes with the first letter as lowercase
- Try avoiding links nested inside buttons, they are not necessary, mostly in this case scenario
- If you want to add the h2 on the links, do it for each link and not one that includes all of them (for SEO practices)
- Try being minimalist with the styles you use; If they are not needed, don't use them to make your code cleaner and easier to understand